# How to implement intrusive data structures in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, undefined-behavior, reinterpret-cast, intrusive-containers

I am porting to C++11 a C code base that makes use of a number of custom intrusive data structures.

In C, the usage patterns will typically look like this:

```c
struct foo {
  // some members
  struct data_structure_node node;
};

// user code

struct *foo = NULL;
struct data_structure_node *result = find_in_data_structure(data_structure, some_key);
if (node) {
  foo = container_of(result, struct data_structure_node, node);
  // use foo
}
```

Here, `container_of` is implemented much like in the Linux kernel:

```c
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({                      \
        const typeof( ((type *)0)->member ) *__mptr = (ptr);    \
        (type *)( (char *)__mptr - offsetof(type,member) );})
```

As the code moves to more idiomatic C++, structures like `foo` typically end up becoming classes that use different access controls, virtual functions, etc. This, in turn, makes them adopt a non [standard layout](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/StandardLayoutType) and causes GCC and clang to emit the following warning when `container_of` is used:

```
error: 'offsetof' within non-standard-layout type 'foo' is conditionally-supported [-Werror=invalid-offsetof]
```

I have been pondering how to implement a safe alternative to the `container_of` macro. Using a *pointers to data member* is the first idea that came to my mind and I'm considering replacing uses of `container_of` by, essentially,

```cpp
template <class Parent, class Member>
Parent* my_container_of(Member *member, Member Parent::* ptr_to_member)
{
    Parent *dummy_parent = nullptr;
    auto *offset_of_member = reinterpret_cast<char *>(&(dummy_parent->*ptr_to_member));
    auto address_of_parent = reinterpret_cast<char *>(member) - offset_of_member;

    return reinterpret_cast<Parent *>(address_of_parent);
}
```

to get `struct foo *` from a `struct data_structure_node *`.

In particular, the use of `ptr_to_member` against the null `dummy_parent` makes me uneasy as it seems equivalent to performing arithmetic on a null pointer, which I understand is undefined behavior (C++11 Standard 5.7.5).

> [...] Unless both pointers point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the behavior is undefined

Boost.Instrusive uses [an approach](https://github.com/boostorg/intrusive/blob/develop/include/boost/intrusive/detail/parent_from_member.hpp#L92) that seems roughly equivalent to `my_container_of()`.

I'm wondering:

- is `my_container_of()` safe?
- is there a cleaner way of achieving this that I'm missing?

Comment: Trying to translate one language to another, line by line, always ends in tears.  Here, it looks like the C code returns a pointer to an object that exists as a member of another object -- the code searches a container of parent objects, of some sort, and then returns a pointer to the member object, and the macros works out the pointer to the parent object. The "cleaner way" would be to analyze this at a higher level, and reimplement the whole function, from scratch -- perhaps as a template -- that returns the "container" itself, rathern than some member, and do it in a type-safe, natural C++.

Comment: To clarify my situation somewhat, the data structures I am using are provided as part of a library that is shared with many other projects (written in C). Reimplementing it in C++ is not a viable option. I am more or less looking for a clean way to wrap it for use in C++ code.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no "clean" way to wrap this kind of C environment in pure, type-safe, C++. One could come close, perhaps, in many ways, but perfection is unachievable here. I found that, in the past, when I made my best guessses as to what the best solution would be, in this kind of a situation where most of the practical details were unknown -- I always ended up wasting my time because the suggested solution turned out to be unacceptable, for some reason that was left out of the original question, but turned out to be a showstopper.

Answer (score 3):

You can do intrusive data structures in C++ even nicer than C. The first thing is to use inheritance. So you try this:

```
struct List {
    List *next{nullptr};
};

struct MyFoo : List {
    MyFoo * get_next() const { return next; }
};
```

But there you get an error that `next` is a `List*` and not a `MyFoo *`. To fix this you can introduce templates:

```
template <typename T>
struct List {
    T *next{nullptr};
};

struct MyFoo : List<MyFoo> {
    MyFoo * get_next() const { return next; }
};
```

Now your intrusive list has the right type for the `next`. But you are limited to one intrusive list per object. So lets extend the template a bit more:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct List {
    T *next{nullptr};
};

class Siblings;
class Children;

struct MyFoo : List<MyFoo, Siblings>, List<MyFoo, Children> {
    using Sibling = List<MyFoo, Siblings>;
    using Child = List<MyFoo, Children>;
    MyFoo * get_sibling() const { return Sibling::next; }
    MyFoo * get_child() const { return Child::next; }
};
```

Now you can inherit as many `List` as you want into a class and scoping the access to access the right `List`. No need of any `offset()` or `container_of` macros.

Note: The Siblings and Children classes are just declarations and purely there to give the `List` different types. They are never defined or instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can implement intrusive data structure by [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). Here is an example of intrusive list.

```cpp
template <typename subtype, typename tag>
struct ilist {
    ilist *prev;
    ilist *next;

    ilist() : prev{this}, next{this} {}

    subtype* self(void) noexcept { return static_cast<subtype*>(this); }
    const subtype* self(void) const noexcept { return static_cast<const subtype*>(this); }

    void link_between(ilist& prev, ilist& next) noexcept {
        this->prev = &prev;
        this->next = &next;
        prev.next = this;
        next.prev = this;
    }

    void add(ilist& node) noexcept {
        node.link_between(*this, *next);
    }
};
```

And then define your foo struct which contains an integer and two intrusive list.

```cpp
struct plink;
struct qlink;

struct foo : ilist<foo, plink>, ilist<foo, qlink> {
    int value;

    foo(int value = 0) : value{value} {}
};
```

And then you can use `ilist<foo, plink>` and `ilist<foo, qlink>` to manage your   intrusive lists.

```cpp
foo a{0}, b{1}, c{2};
ilist<foo, plink> p;
ilist<foo, qlink> q;

p.add(a); p.add(b); p.add(c); // p contains a, b and c

q.add(a); q.add(c); // q contains a and c

for (auto it = p.next; it != &p; it = it->next) {
    foo* f = it->self();
    // do something on foo f
}
```

Godbolt demo: https://godbolt.org/z/o56hYob86